# Firestore create collection without adding any document

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a collection without creating any document in it. But not by first, creating the document, and then deleting the doc. I tried something, but still when I delete the document, my collection is being deleted too.

[Firestore image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfDIN.png)

```java
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        DocumentReference roomReference = db.collection("messagingRooms").document();

        List<String> partners = new ArrayList<>();
        partners.add("my_id");
        partners.add("it's id");


        Map<String ,Object> newRoom = new HashMap<>();
        newRoom.put("partners", partners);
        newRoom.put("roomID", roomReference.getId());

        roomReference.set(newRoom)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                        Map<String, Object> newMessage  = new HashMap<>();

                       DocumentReference messageReference =  roomReference.collection("messages").document();

                        messageReference.set(newMessage)
                               .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                       
                                      db.collection("messagingRooms")
                                              .document(roomReference.getId())
                                              .collection("messages")
                                              .document(messageReference.getId())
                                              .delete()
                                              .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                  @Override
                                                  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                      Log.v("Mok", messageReference.getId());
                                                  }
                                              });
                                   }
                               });

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.v("Error_1", e.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be very helpful to provide us some code withyour problem! :)

Comment: thank you, I added source code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way of creating a collection without any document in firestore. If you check the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#collections), the last paragraph says:

> *You do not need to "create" or "delete" collections. After you create the first document in a collection, the collection exists. If you delete all of the documents in a collection, it no longer exists.*

So, a collection needs at least one document in it.